# Регулярные краши Visual Basic 6 на Windows 7

Tags: visual-basic

У меня установлена среда Visual Basic 6, ОС Windows 7 x64
Думаю, как и у многих при добавлении контролов на форму были лаги (подробнее в этом видео https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WHEf7K8nw3g)
Решил проблему как в видео, поставил галку "Отключить композицию рабочего стола"
Лаги исчезли, но сам Visual Basic стал работать нестабильно, регулярно стали вылетать краши и сообщения "Out of memory"(Возможно эти сообщения не из за этого)
Есть ли другие способы убрать лаги или что можно сделать чтобы Visual Basic работал стабильно?
P.S. Я не уверен что проблема в галочке. Но с тех пор как я убрал галочку ни одного краша

> Сигнатура проблемы:
>     Имя события проблемы: APPCRASH
>     Имя приложения:   VB6.EXE
>     Версия приложения:    6.0.81.76
>     Отметка времени приложения:   3592011f
>     Имя модуля с ошибкой: VB6.EXE
>     Версия модуля с ошибкой:  6.0.81.76
>     Отметка времени модуля с ошибкой: 3592011f
>     Код исключения:   c0000005
>     Смещение исключения:  00002b1a
>     Версия ОС:    6.1.7601.2.1.0.256.1
>     Код языка:    1049
>     Дополнительные сведения 1:    7e3b
>     Дополнительные сведения 2:    7e3beb1e9ccf6d519c5b994ca59a280f
>     Дополнительные сведения 3:    7b83
>     Дополнительные сведения 4:    7b833c57ebcf54809fd3aaccd8ea4f46

[image: Visual Basic не отвечает]

Comment: Может не мое дело, но какой смысл сейчас использовать VB6?

Comment: Безусловно, это устаревший язык. Но я программирую на нем уже много лет и проще  сделать на том, что хорошо знаю чем учить что-то новое

Comment: Не знаю даже что сказать по этому поводу. Могу только пожелать удачи. Но вообще, это тот случай когда пора слезть с мертвой лошади.